# Firestore database transactions not behaving as expected

Tags: typescript, firebase

When running firebase database transactions, they fail; but no error is thrown.

Given the following code:

Code:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const db = admin.firestore();

class Doc {
  first = 0;
  second = 0;
  third = 0;
  id = Math.random();
  constructor(data: any) {
    if (data) Object.assign(this, data);
    this.first += 1;
    this.second += 2;
    this.third += 3;
    console.log(this);
  }
  serialze() {
    return {
      first: this.first,
      second: this.second,
      third: this.third,
      id: this.id,
    };
  }
}

export function runSingleTransaction() {
  return db
    .runTransaction(async (transaction) => {
      const docSnapshot = await db
        .collection("transaction-test")
        .doc("base-test")
        .get();
      let doc = docSnapshot.data();
      const writeDoc = new Doc(doc);
      if (doc) transaction.update(docSnapshot.ref, writeDoc.serialze());
      else transaction.set(docSnapshot.ref, writeDoc.serialze());
      return writeDoc;
    }, {})
    .then((wd) => {
      console.log("the transaction passed");
      return wd;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("the transaction failed");
      return err;
    });
}
```

Index:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import {runSingleTransaction } from "./entrypoints";

export const runTransaction = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (request, response) => {
    response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    const i = await runSingleTransaction();
    response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ res: i }));
  }
);
```

Test:

```
  it.only("should run db transactions in practice", async () => {
    const ret = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const res = axios.get(
        "http://localhost:5001/guestfeedback-2f0f8/us-central1/runTransaction"
      );
      ret.push(res);
    }
    await Promise.all(ret);
  });
```

This is the output:
[image: firestore emulator]
[image: logs emulator]

Expected:
In firestore we should see an increment by 10 so the property first should be 10 second should be 20 and third should be 30

In the logs we should see it fail and retry several times as writes are happening concurrently. however all logs are passing.

Is this the best way to handle concurrency? if so; what am I missing?
if not; what is the correct way to handle this use case?

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in my code, it should have been :

```
(transaction) => {
  ...
  const docRef = db
          .collection("transaction-test")
          .doc("base-test")
  const docSnapshot = transaction.get(docRef)
  ...
}
```